# Navigating from one component to the other component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, community

I am new to Lightning components and here when I am trying to navigate one component to the other component I am getting this error.

[image: **enter image description here**]

Here is my code components.

Onclick Component

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable" >
<aura:attribute name="Txt" type="String" default=""/>
<div class="slds-box slds-theme_default">
    This is component 1.<br/><br/>
    <lightning:input type="text" value="{!v.Txt}" label="Enter Text : "/><br/><br/>
 <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Navigate" onclick="{!c.navigateToComTwo}"/>
</div>
```

```
    ({
    navigateToComTwo : function(component, event, helper) {
        var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
        evt.setParams({
            componentDef : "c:childComp",
            componentAttributes: {    

            }
        });
        evt.fire();
      }
  })
```

Child Component

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable">

<aura:attribute name="Text" type="String" default=""/>
<div class="slds-box slds-theme_default">

 <lightning:button variant="brand" label="Back to Component One" onclick="{!c.navigateToComOne}"/>
</div>
```

```
    ({
    navigateToComOne : function(component, event, helper) {
        var evt = $A.get("e.force:navigateToComponent");
        evt.setParams({
            componentDef : "c:onClickComp",
            componentAttributes: {    
            }
        });
        evt.fire();
     }
   })
```

Please help me out from this.

Answer (score 0):

Migrate to lightning:isUrlAddressable from force:navigateToComponent which is supported in **Lightning Experience, Lightning Communities, Salesforce Mobile App**.

The pageReference JavaScript object represents a URL for a page. You can use a pageReference instead of parsing or creating a URL directly. This approach helps you avoid broken navigation if Salesforce changes URL formats in the future.

Add `<lightning:navigation aura:id="navigationService" />` to your component markup, and update it to use **navigationService**. Pass in a pageReference.

```
cmp.find("navigationService").navigate({
    type: "standard__component",
    attributes: {
        componentName: "c__myCmpCopy" 
    },
    state: { 
        "c__myAttr": "foo" 
    }
});
```

References:-

1. [Aura Component Navigation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:navigation/documentation)
2. [Migrate to lightning:isUrlAddressable from force:navigateToComponent](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/components_navigation_migrate_to_isUrlAddressable.htm)
3. [Aura Component Navigate To Component](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToComponent/specification)

> Starting in API version 43.0, the force:navigateToComponent event is
>   deprecated.Also, It is not defined by Salesforce where it is supported.

The code you have seems to be fine. It seems to be not supported in communities and standalone application. When you try to navigate with the same piece of code in home page or record or app page, It works pretty fine.